# Riverbed - StateNotifierProvider - give initial value as a parameter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

As per the official document [StateNotifierProvider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider) it's working fine, but I have a scenario to pass some value at the initial stage, flow is going like this, I have a list of items, and after clicking on it, it will be redirected to the details screen, when user swipe left or right with [PageView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) title hast be updated, it's working fine when user swipe the page, but when user clicks on the 3rd item from the list I want to show title with the selected item, so I want to pass initial position to **StateNotifierProvider**

class ControllerPositionNotifier extends StateNotifier {
final currentPosition;

```
  ControllerPositionNotifier(this.currentPosition) : super(currentPosition);

  int position(int position) {
    return state = position;
  }
}
```

I want to pass a my value when I enter into widget **ControllerPositionNotifier(MY_ARG)**

```
 final controllerPositionNotifier = StateNotifierProvider<ControllerPositionNotifier, int>((ref) {
      return ControllerPositionNotifier(0);
    });
```

View pager screen

```
class SongWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final List<dynamic>? resultData;
  final int position;

  const SongWidget({Key? key, required this.resultData, required this.position})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SongWidgetState createState() => _SongWidgetState();
}

class _SongWidgetState extends ConsumerState<SongWidget> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final songs = widget.resultData?.map((e) => Song.fromJson(e)).toList() ??
        List<Song>.empty();

    int position = ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier);

    // HERE I WANT TO PASS ON MY ARGUMENT widget.position
   
    final PageController controller =
        PageController(initialPage: widget.position);

    print('_SongWidgetState');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(songs[position].sTitle ?? '--'),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: songs.length,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          print('position: $index');
          ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier.notifier).position(index);
        },

        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Text(
                    songs[index].sSong ?? '--',
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This line hast be updated the initial stage

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(songs[position].sTitle ?? '--'),
      )
```

After swipe updating successfully

```
ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier.notifier).position(index);
```

But I would like to pass some value at the initial stage

Comment: *I have a scenario to pass some value at the initial stage* try [`.family`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family)  on provider

Comment: **StateNotifierProvider.family expecting three parameters

**final controllerPositionNotifier = StateNotifierProvider.family<ControllerPositionNotifier, int,int>((ref,position) {
  return ControllerPositionNotifier(position);
});

**initial value working 
 int position = ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier(widget.position));

***not updating the value 

**onPageChanged: (index) {
          print('position: $index');
          ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier(index).notifier).position(index);
        },

Answer (score 0):

Use the new api from riverpod 2.0 to pass the parameter:

```dart
final controllerPositionNotifier = NotifierProviderFamily<ControllerPositionNotifier, int, int>(
    ControllerPositionNotifier.new,
  );

class ControllerPositionNotifier extends FamilyNotifier<int, int> {

  @override
  int build(int index) {
    // here you can safely watch on providers
    return index;
  }
}
```

In the widget it will look like this:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int position = ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier(widget.position));
   
    final PageController controller =
        PageController(initialPage: position);
    ...
}
```

**Note**: use `ref.read` in the callbacks

```dart
ref.read(controllerPositionNotifier(position).notifier).position(index);
```

Comment: I don't know where I am making the mistake, I followed your code, but it did not help me, Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

To provide initial value when I get into the widget, I did update the provider before entering into the widget

```
child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: dataValue.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    ref
                                        .watch(
                                            controllerPositionNotifier.notifier)
                                        .position(index);
                                    final result =
                                        Song.fromJson(dataValue[index]);
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => SongWidget(
                                                  resultData: dataValue,
                                                  position: index,
                                                )));
                                  },
                                  child: SongItem(data: dataValue[index]));
                            },
                          ),
```

I did update the value, inside onTap() before moving to the *SongWidget*

```
ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier.notifier).position(index);
```

onTap() - method

```
return InkWell(onTap: () {
     ref.watch(controllerPositionNotifier.notifier).position(index);
  });
```

Comment: you still use `ref.watch` in the callbacks... This will definitely lead to an error

Comment: Using ref.read should be avoided as much as possible because it is not reactive.

It exists for cases where using watch or listen would cause issues. If you can, it is almost always better to use watch/listen, especially watch.

https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-refread-to-obtain-the-state-of-a-provider

still is it fine to use - watch or read? I am new to riverpod

Comment: And then follow the same link : _CAUTION
The watch method should not be called asynchronously, like inside an onPressed of an ElevatedButton. Nor should it be used inside initState and other State life-cycles.

In those cases, consider using ref.read instead._